# href= tag in Joomla 2.5 .ini file

Tags: href, ini

how can I insert href tag into joomla 2.5 .ini file ? any idea?

I am trying like this:

`YOU_ARE_ALREADY_REGISTERED=You alreade registered.<br />Go back <a href="http://www.joomla.org">http://www.joomla.org</a>`